# Troubles while parsing with python very large xml file

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have a large xml file (about 84MB) which is in this form:

```
<books>
    <book>...</book>
    ....
    <book>...</book>
</books>
```

My goal is to extract every single book and get its properties. I tried to parse it (as I did with other xml files) as follows:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString

fd = "myfile.xml"
parser = parse(fd)
## other python code here
```

but the code seems to fail in the parse instruction. Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

I should point out that the file may contain greek, spanish and arabic characters.

This is the output i got in ipython:

```
In [2]: fd = "myfile.xml"

In [3]: parser = parse(fd)
Killed
```

I would like to point out that the computer freezes during the execution, so this may be related to memory consumption as stated below.

Comment: Could you provide stack trace here?

Comment: doing python myparser.py the shell is killed. I forgot to say that I have non ascii characters...can this be a problem?

Comment: @user601836: provide the failure message.

Comment: @akira: I suspect it's running out of memory.  I've seen `minidom` use ~400MB of memory to parse a ~10MB XML document.  If `minidom`s memory usage scales linearly with the size of the XML document, then I'd expect `minidom` would be trying to use ~3.5GB here.

Comment: my output is in the question now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using a SAX parser here.  I wouldn't recommend using `minidom` on any XML document larger than a few megabytes; I've seen it use about 400MB of RAM reading in an XML document that was about 10MB in size.  I suspect the problems you are having are being caused by `minidom` requesting too much memory.

Python comes with an XML SAX parser.  To use it, do something like the following.

```
from xml.sax.handlers import ContentHandler
from xml.sax import parse

class MyContentHandler(ContentHandler):
    # override various ContentHandler methods as needed...


handler = MyContentHandler()
parse("mydata.xml", handler)
```

Your `ContentHandler` subclass will override various methods in [ContentHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.handler.html#contenthandler-objects) (such as `startElement`, `startElementNS`, `endElement`, `endElementNS` or `characters`.  These handle events generated by the SAX parser as it reads your XML document in.

SAX is a more 'low-level' way to handle XML than DOM; in addition to pulling out the relevant data from the document, your ContentHandler will need to do work keeping track of what elements it is currently inside.  On the upside, however, as SAX parsers don't keep the whole document in memory, they can handle XML documents of potentially any size, including those larger than yours.

I haven't tried other using DOM parsers such as lxml on XML documents of this size, but I suspect that lxml will still take a considerable time and use a considerable amount of memory to parse your XML document.  That could slow down your development if every time you run your code you have to wait for it to read in an 84MB XML document.

Finally, I don't believe the Greek, Spanish and Arabic characters you mention will cause a problem.

Answer (score 8):

Try with [lxml](http://lxml.de/) which is more easy to use.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from lxml import etree

with open("myfile.xml") as fp:
    tree = etree.parse(fp)
    root = tree.getroot()

    print root.tag

    for book in root:
        print book.text
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 species of XML parsers (this applies to any language).

1. DOM parsing (which is what you are using). In this type the whole XML file is read into a memory structures and then accessed by methods.
2. SAX parsing. This is a parsing algorithm that reads each piece of XML in a step-wise fashion. This technique would allow you to better detect and deal with errors.

In general DOM is easier than SAX because a lot of the gritty details are dealt with by its native methods.

SAX is a bit more of a challenge because you have to code methods that the SAX parsing "runs" during is walk of the XML document.